# How to lazily set BOOL property in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, getter-setter

I need a BOOL property on a data structure, representing the state of some object in a database, and I want to set that property lazily -- that is, I don't want to ping the db until I need to, and only set the property at that point (i.e., the first time I get it).

For something like an NSString, I'd make a getter like

```
- (NSString *)myString {
    if (!_myString) {

        // ask db for value
        _myString = [value returned from db]

    }
    return _myString;
}
```

But it seems BOOLs default to NO in Objective-C -- which means I would never know whether the value is in fact NO, or I just haven't ever gotten it yet. I have poked around, but I can't seem to figure out how to create the kind of getter I have in mind for such a property. Any suggestions? Or am I missing something quite obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of a bool you could use an NSNumber that can also store true/false values, then you can test whether the NSNumber is nil or not

Comment: you could also just use an int that is initialized to -1, then you can set it to 0 or 1 if its true or false, and you can know its not been lazy loaded yet if its -1

Comment: @Fonix use int is a good idea

Comment: Using an integer is good. You could also just use two booleans, one to hold the value and another to indicate if the first is valid / has been initialized.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an NSNumber in the inside of object:

```
// .h
@interface Object : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool;

@end

//.m
@interface Object ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *myBoolFromDB;

@end

@implementation Object

- (BOOL) myBool {
    if (_myBoolFromDB == nil) {
        ...
    }
    return [_myBoolFromDB boolValue];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you only need to do this initialization once, and **not once per instance** of the class, `dispatch_once()` can be a nice tool:

```
- (BOOL)myBool {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        // initialize _myBool here
    });
    return _myBool;
}
```

From a practical standpoint, it's really not so different from other solutions: you need to remember whether you've already initialized the state *somehow*, and whether you do it by storing your state in a pointer that can be nil, or in an `int` that can have some "uninitialized" value, or in a static `once` variable doesn't make much difference codifies.

What I like about this method, though, is that it clearly conveys your intention: you want this thing to happen the only first time `myBool` is called. It also lets you store your `myBool` property as a `BOOL` rather than as some other type that you have to translate to a `BOOL`, which again more clearly communicates your intention.

Comment: This is quite dangerous if you don't understand what you're doing. If there are multiple instances of the class, then this won't work right. There's only one `once` variable for the class, not one per instance. So, once `-myBool` has been called on any instance, the "initialize _myBool here" code will be run for that instance and then never again, neither for that instance nor any other.

Comment: @KenThomases Agree completely! I may have assumed too much here. I'll edit to make that clear. Thanks for catching that.